# Segmentation fault 11 when installing composer on OSX 10.9.2

Tags: php, macos

I've been trying to install composer, but keeps getting error "Segmentation fault:11".
Below is a list of what I have tried:

1. sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

   Output:

   #!/usr/bin/env php
      All settings correct for using Composer
      Segmentation fault: 11
2. - Reinstall command line tools
   - Update homebrew
   - Install php54 and composer using homebrew

   This one succeeds, but when I tried to type "composer" in my command line,
   it gives the following output:

   /usr/local/bin/composer: line 3: 27938 Segmentation fault: 11  /usr/bin/env php -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off /usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar $*

I've also tried using the older alpha builds, and all of them gives the same segmentation fault 11 error

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not much of a clue I'd guess there is some incompatibility with the libraries. You could try running `composer install` . I've solved some homebrew issues by removing packages and reinstalling them. I'd open an issue on https://github.com/composer/composer/issues

Comment: thanks. `composer install` doesn't work though, it gives the same output as `composer`

Comment: why are you using `sudo`? im guessing that's the problem, try just installing it with out `sudo`

Comment: I tried `sudo` because the normal command gives segmentation fault 11 error as well

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my error was caused by misconfigured php.ini file.
Restoring it using php.ini.default solves the problem