# Segmentation fault when trying to install Drush with Composer

Tags: segmentation-fault, composer-php, git-bash, drush

I am trying to install Drush by using `$ composer global require drush/drush:8.*` through the Git-bash CLI, but I get a segmentation fault error:

`/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer: line 18: 10444 Segmentation fault php "${dir}/composer.phar" $*`

I am on a Windows 10 computer.

Anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the problem, that PHP takes too much resources, PHP could be compiled with the unsupported settings (`php -i | head`), it's caused by some extensions (e.g. caching or XDebug, check by: `php -i | grep xdebug`) or simply a PHP bug.

To fix it, revert your `php.ini` into default settings (see [GH #2839](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2839)) as it may be [misconfigured](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22615256/55075), alternatively disable unnecessary extensions (such as [XDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32573924/55075)) or try to upgrade your PHP into newer version.